# Find maximum and minimum value of a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, max, return-value, min

I have this code wrote in python 3:

```
matrix = []
    loop = True
    while loop:
        line = input()
        if not line: 
            loop = False
        values = line.split()
        row = [int(value) for value in values]
        matrix.append(row)

    print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix]))
    print('matrix saved')
```

an example of returned matrix would be [[1,2,4],[8,9,0]].Im wondering of how I could find the maximum and minimum value of a matrix? I tried the max(matrix) and min(matrix) built-in function of python but it doesnt work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for vector distances?

Comment: umm no, just to find the max and min value of a matrix; for example with the matrix [[1,2,4],[8,9,0]] , max value would be 9 and min value would be 0. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in functions `max()` and `min()` after stripping the list of lists:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 4], [8, 9, 0]]
dup = []
for k in matrix:
    for i in k:
        dup.append(i)

print (max(dup), min(dup))
```

This runs as:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 4], [8, 9, 0]]
>>> dup = []
>>> for k in matrix:
...     for i in k:
...         dup.append(i)
... 
>>> print (max(dup), min(dup))
(9, 0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 16):

One-liner:

for max:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 4], [8, 9, 0]]
print (max(map(max, matrix))
9
```

for min:

```
print (min(map(min, matrix))
0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use new data structures and are looking for the smallest amount of code possible:

```
max_value = max([max(l) for l in matrix])
min_value = min([min(l) for l in matrix])
```

If you don't want to go through the matrix twice:

```
max_value = max(matrix[0])
min_value = min(matrix[0])

for row in matrix[1:]:
    max_value = max(max_value, max(row))
    min_value = min(min_value, min(row))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with the solution of flattening matrix in an array, instead of inner loop you can just use extend:

```
big_array = []

for arr in matrix:
   big_array.extend(arr)

print(min(big_array), max(big_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
largest = 0
smallest = 0
count = 0
for i in matrix:
    for j in i:
        if count == 0:
            largest = j
            smallest = j
            count = 1
        if j > largest:
            largest = j
        if j < smallest:
            smallest = j
```

UPDATE

For splitting

```
largest = 0
count = 0
for i in matrix:
    for j in i:
        if count == 0:
            largest = j
        if j > largest:
            largest = j
```

and do the same thing for smallest

Comment: I forgot that you need to set smallest to the first element so that it won't always be 0

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, but how if I would prefer to have 2 separated module? One for max and one for min? Thank you

Comment: Updated for splitting

Answer (score 0):

here is what i came up with

```
M = [[1,2,4],[8,9,0]]

def getMinMax( M ):
    maxVal = 0
    for row in M:
        if max(row) > maxVal: maxVal = max(row)
    minVal = maxVal*1
    for row in M:
        if min(row) < minVal: minVal = min(row)

    return ( minVal,  maxVal )

getMinMax( M )
// Result: (0, 9) //
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first decide to flatten this matrix and then find the corresponding maximum and minimum values as indicated below
Convert the matrix to a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [8, 9, 0]])
mat_flattened = matrix.flatten()
min_val = min(mat_flattened)
max_val = max(mat_flattened)
```