# Python minimum value of matrix

Tags: python, matrix

Say I have a matrix like the following.

```
[[1,2]
 [3,4]]
```

I want the number 1 to be returned as the minimum.
Currently I have

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
min([min(element) for element in a])
>> 1
```

**Is there a more efficient way of doing this?**
 I don't like my solution above. I tried `min(a)` which gives an error. I have read the answers provided in
[Find maximum and minimum value of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399801/find-maximum-and-minimum-value-of-a-matrix) and I feel that what I have is slightly better?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html

Comment: @MooingRawr Thanks :) It works perfectly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given your matrix

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

You can just call the `min` method off your matrix

```
>>> a.min()
1
```

Or call the free function `min` and pass in your matrix

```
>>> np.min(a)
1
```

Comment: damn, I feel dumb now :)  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't let me accept answer right now, I'll accept when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Given matrix,

```
>> matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Passing a list of numbers to min(), returns the minimum value.
Since, matrix is a list of lists, map() can be used to find minimum value for the each sub-list present in the matrix. Since, map returns an iterator, min can be applied again to find the resultant minimum.

```
>> min(map(min, matrix))
>> 1
```

But this operation is bit costly I don't recommend you to use in a production environment. It can be used to just test and debug stuff.